# C# Program that checks on the status of the Capslock with each character insert

Tags: c#, beginner

The following is my first successful running C# program.

The lessons that I personally learnt through this include:

- The value of asking for help after having tried several times
- The advantages of being adaptable about one's methods of reaching an end
- The (a?) proper placement of functions in relation to a main program
- How to pass information into and out of such functions
- How to use a loop to leverage code (doing the same stuff over and over)
- How to collect character input from the User & I'm sure there's more...

In any case this code appears to work. I know that it doesn't hold a candle to much of the stuff you guys put up but on the bright side its short and kind of readable (both aims of mine).

Could some much brighter spark than me kindly shine a light on the stuff that could have been done better (or simply provide some advice or suggested direction)? :c)

```
using System;
namespace CapsChecker
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                //Set up an infinite loop for program to run within 
            while (true)
            {
                    //Collection of user input
                Console.Write("Press a key: ");
                char input = (Console.ReadKey().KeyChar);
                    //Check if Capslock is on when key entered. Combined with 
                    //the shift button this can result in CapsCheck returning
                    //true even if key entered is lower case.
                if (CapsCheck() == true)
                {
                    CapsNotify(true);   
                }
                else
                {
                    CapsNotify(false);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();

                switch (input) //Abandoned '.Key' enum
                {
                    case 'Q':
                        { break; } 
                    default:
                        { continue; }
                }
                break; //Afterthoght as it wasn't breaking on capital Q.
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Program ending. Press a key.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static bool CapsCheck()
        {
                // Check if Capslock is Active
            if (Console.CapsLock == true)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        static void CapsNotify(bool caps)
        {
                // Notify whether Capslock is Active
            if (caps == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" Capslock is Active.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" Capslock is Inactive.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work on Linux with X Windows / Mir. I don't really know *how* one would check for caps lock being turned on in a PTY.

Comment: Sorry that it didn't work for you cat. If it helps I'm using Visual Studio 2015 (community) on a Windows 7 machine (I really don't like prompts telling me to upgrade to 10 ^_~).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

#### `if true return true else return false` antipattern

Unecessary `if` statements when dealing with booleans is a very common beginner pitfall.

```
    static bool CapsCheck()
    {
            // Check if Capslock is Active
        if (Console.CapsLock == true)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Is equivalent to:

```
   static bool CapsCheck()
   {
       return Console.CapsLock;
   }
```

As a further simplification, you may use `Console.CapsLock` directly and avoid this function.

Another boolean simplification is

```
            if (CapsCheck() == true)
            {
                CapsNotify(true);   
            }
            else
            {
                CapsNotify(false);
            }
```

To:

```
 CapsNotify( CapsCheck() );
```

Or:

```
CapsNotify( Console.CapsLock );
```

#### Ternary simplification

In `CapsNotify` it is unecessary to use a full `if` `else`, a ternary is enough and simpler:

```
 Console.Writeline("CapsLock is" + (caps ? "Active" : "Inactive"));
```

Comment: Thank you very kindly Caridorc! I just tested your modification suggestions and it works perfectly. Not that I doubted you - I just had to try the shiny new tool in my c# toolbox. :c)

Comment: Ternary operators are often frowned upon in commercial environments for the sake of clarity of code.

Comment: @Killroy Ternaries are simpler than if / else, if / else allows statements too, ternary only expressions. How can a simpler tool be said to hurt clarity?

Comment: I've found that C programmers are adverse to the ternary for some (what I'm sure is a very good in that environment) reason. In the managed world of .Net, the ternary is good for simple assignments, but if it begins to become complicated, it's better to switch to the more verbose way. We like ternaries on my team, but disallow any nested ternaries from in our code base.

Comment: @RubberDuck like `goto`, It has its uses and is not always obfuscated. `printf("BOB says: It seems that guess is wrong%s\n\n", game_over ? "; you lose!" : ", enter another!");`

Comment: I'm an old C programmer and I have no problem with Ternary, it definitely has it's uses.

Comment: Perhaps comments are a good way to mitigate the risk of excess complexity in resorting to a dense use of Terniaries?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine($"CapsLock is {caps? "Active" : "Inactive"}");` is arguably more understandable.

Comment: Just commenting on common coding standards at AAA studios. Not on my personal preference. I've started adjusting my practices to align, rathern than being forced to change whenever I touch a foreign code base.

Comment: The only problem with using ternary operators when cobbling together strings is that it makes it impossible to localize the application later on. So better to not learn bad habits that you later have to unlearn.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of using a forever loop with a `break`, which as you found out, [gets complicated when there's a switch involved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044752/breaking-out-of-a-foreach-loop-from-within-a-switch-block), evaluate your end condition inside of your while.

So instead of

```
while(true)
{
    //...

     switch (input) //Abandoned '.Key' enum
     {
        case 'Q':
           { break; } 
        default:
            { continue; }
      }
      break; //Afterthoght as it wasn't breaking on capital Q.
        }
```

You can just do this

```
char input = default(char);

do
{

    //...

} while (input != 'Q');
```

Because you always want your main loop to execute at least once.

See the [msdn doc for `do...while` loops](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/370s1zax.aspx) for more information.

Comment: A very good point RubberDuck. :c) I admit that I ran into a little trouble with input being defined from within the loop (and not being retained for the condition). Do you have any suggestion as how to easily skirt this problem?

Comment: I'm betting you tried `while(input != 'Q')` first, right? Try the `do...while`. I'm pretty confident that it'll solve your problem @Avestron

Comment: Actually I commented out the 'while...' code at the top, adding a 'do' line in its place. Commented out the Switch statement. Finally added 'while(input != 'Q')' after the close curly bracket after the second commented out break statement... :c)

Comment: @Avestron Yeah, the `do {} while()` loop cannot test a variable that was defined inside its body (the `{}`). You can either declare it before the `do`, or use your previous code, but have a `bool` value that is set to true if the key is Q, and do the break outside the `switch`.

Comment: Woah. Hold up @Kroltan. No harm in declaring it outside the loop using the default. http://www.dotnetperls.com/default

Comment: @RubberDuck Indeed, you can actually leave it unitialised _if_ it is always initialised within the loop (or pedantically, even if its not initialized, but that triggers a warning and leads to unexpected behaviour). Not discrediting the do...while solution, just giving alternative options.

Comment: Thank you both. Will try the outer declaration first - when I get back. ^_^

Comment: Back. :c) Placing: char input; before the beginning of the loop (and removing the 'char' before 'input' during user input phase) did the trick :c) Still works well and its neater! Thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you kindly for all the feedback received. I have learnt a lot from the experience. :c)

Since it would be inappropriate to edit my original post I shall instead post the complete revised code as a wiki answer. It incorporates much of the suggestions received and I do believe it to be a big improvement upon the original.

The code is much shorter if more heavily-commented.

```
using system;
namespace CapsChecker
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                //input declared before primary program loop 
                //to permit for conditional purposes
            char input;
            do
            {
                    //Collection of User Input
                Console.Write("Press a key: ");
                input = (Console.ReadKey().KeyChar);
                    //Check if Capslock is on when key entered. Combined with 
                    //the shift button this can result in CapsCheck returning
                    //true even if key entered is lower case.
                    //
                    //The 'CapsNotify' method returns a result based on
                    //the inserted parameter in the form of 
                    //the return of the CapsCheck method
                Console.WriteLine();
                CapsNotify(CapsCheck());                
            }
            while (input != 'Q');
            Console.WriteLine("Program shutting down. Press a key.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static bool CapsCheck()
        {
                // Check if Capslock is active
                // Return true if Caps is active
            return Console.CapsLock;
        }

        static void CapsNotify(bool caps)
        {
                //Notify whether Capslock is Active
                //In-line check of caps results in accurate output.
            Console.WriteLine("CapsLock is {0}.", (caps ? "Active" : "Inactive"));
        }
    }
}
```

Again, thank you and feel free to provide more feedback for improvement if such pleases your kind self. ^_^